# node-postgres reconnect when connection failed

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, promise

This is my `db connection` code of `nodejs` project, in some situation my db is `down` (`not working`), i want to try `reconnecting to db`, but i don't know how to that, please help me

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const postgis = new Client({
  user: process.env.PGUSER,
  host: process.env.PGHOST,
  database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
  password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
  port: process.env.PGPORT
});
console.log(`Connecting to PostGIS database ${process.env.PGDATABASE} on: ${process.env.PGHOST}:${process.env.PGPORT}`);

postgis.connect()
.then(() => {
  console.log(`PostGIS connected to: ${process.env.PGDATABASE} on: ${process.env.PGHOST}:${process.env.PGPORT}`)
})
    .catch((e) => {
  // console.error(`PostGIS connection error: ${e}`)
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("entering again")
    postgis.connect();
  }, 10000);

});
```

error:

```
(node:10299) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10299) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: You cannot reconnect to the same client, you have to recreate a new client

Answer (score 2):

You can handle it in catch block and reconnect to posgres

```
setTimeout(function () {
      postgis.connect();
    }, 10000);
```

Comment: (node:10299) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10299) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.